# Error in calculating difference between two Unix timestamp in php

Tags: time, php

I have a function which calculate the difference between two timestamps,

```
public static function getDuration($from, $to) {
    $duration = $to - $from; 
    return $duration;
}
```

but this is not working as required.
example, if i pass,

```
$difference = getDuration(strtotime('19-07-2012 23:00:00'), strtotime('20-07-2012 4:45:00'));
echo $difference/3600;
```

it returns 5.75 instead of 5.45, when converted to hours.

Comment: That result is correct 5+0.75*60 = 5h 45m

Comment: Learn basic decimal math? Just one possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it returns ok - 5,75 is 5 3/4 hours = 5 hours 45 minutes

It returns in decimal - not hours/minutes

if you want hours/minutes you can use:

```
$hours=floor($difference/3600);
$minutes=$difference/60-$hours*60;
```